# How to display '0' for a certain field containing NULL using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am creating a database for the products that are received in a company. There is a separate table for the products in stock which contains a field by the name Quantity which shows NULL if the item has not been received yet. Now I need to display '0' for the same condition i.e. not yet received. How can I do this using a stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

With these three methods you can display 0 instead of `NULL`:

```
1. ISNULL(MyColumn, 0)
2. SELECT CASE WHEN MyColumn IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE MyColumn END FROM MyTable
3. SELECT COALESCE(MyCoumn, 0) FROM MyTable
```